# Installed required packages on the host system but facing missing packages issue in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have all the packages required to run the ipynb file on my computer, but while I run the notebook file, I get the error message 'No module named 'plotly'' (for example).

'plotly' has actually been installed on the system, and even if I install it in a previous step in the notebook file, I get the same error message.

I am not really sure if it is a problem with sync between the system and notebook file or I'm missing something really obvious here.

The same holds true many other packages and libraries.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you install jupyter using anaconda or with pip install jupyter? Also, could this be a PATH issue?

Comment: Is the jupyter notebook and the packages like plotly installed in the same virtualenv?

Comment: @JoshWilkins I installed with pip install jupyter. And its not a path issue, I explicitly mentioned the absolute path for each bag file.

Comment: @Adonis I am a little confused about this. I have two versions of Python currently and I only installed python 3 recently just for this. Are you suggesting that I install the plotly and other packages separately for both the versions of python?

Comment: That could indeed be the problem. One thing you can try is on the command line with which you start `jupyter` to start a python interpreter and check if the import works or not

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince7 The fact that you have several python interpreters is relevant as well as which python has plotly installed and which python kernel are you using to run the notebook (they must match in order to use plotly in the notebook).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the problem was that most of the packages were installed, by default, for Python 2. I had to re-install all the packages separately for Python 3 (Jupyter Notebook).

pip install *package-name*

pip3 install *package-name*

Not all the packages are available for Python 3 but thankfully, all the ones I needed were easily obtained. Hope this helps someone and thank you all for the suggestions :)